# Scheduling WP cron jobs

Tags: wp-cron, cron

I am new with cron jobs and I have to schedule cron jobs. There are a lot of cron jobs in my website which are running randomly but I want all these to run at specific time. Actually I do not want these cron jobs to run at day time and instead I want these to run at night because these are significantly slowing down the server. 
Mostly these are firing via plugins so I do not have control over these functions directly.
Is there a way to control schedule for these cron jobs. Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you could use something like this, [WP Crontrol](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/) to see what those events might be and when they are scheduled to run ( interval ), but the time of the day ( when they run ) is controlled by visitors viewing your site ( which is why they run during the day, because that when your site has most traffic).  The only way around this is to run it server side or a service that provides such actions.

Answer (score 0):

WP Crontrol is a good solution, or you could disable WP-Cron completely and run the cron jobs from the server (or a service like EasyCron) on whatever schedule you want.

To disable WP-Cron, in 'wp-cron.php' add:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also use [Advanced Cron Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-cron-manager/) plugin as you can pause any cron events that are running in your site system, and to remove it if you need.

Answer (score 0):

First disable schedule executions as a side effect of normal http requests to your website `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);` in `wp-config.php`.

Second use [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org/) to execute schedules via `crontab -e`.

`0 2 * * * wp cron event run --path=/path/to/wp/docroot --due-now`

This executes all your schedules at two o'clock. But beware that **all** schedules will only be executed at this time so you planned post will not be published until two o'clock the next day for example.